I try to install mysqlclient on my linux computer by using pip install mysqlclinet but give me error
pip install mysqlclient --break-system-packages
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Skipping /usr/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/argcomplete-3.1.4.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]
Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2qns_fsc/overlay/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2qns_fsc/overlay/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2qns_fsc/overlay/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 155, in 
File "", line 49, in get_config_posix
File "", line 28, in find_package_name
Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
I try by using pip install mysqlclient and I expect it to run correct
